# duplicate elimination with time

Tags: sql, postgresql

For my Smart home Stuff I create a Database, but I make a mistake during programming: the application posting stuff into the Database twice. I want to delete all rows, which contain duplicates. With duplicate I mean a tuples what is identically in the data to the last one from the same type. I mark the duplicates in this Example with "<<" please pay also attention to the last 3 rows. I want to keep the first new Data so I want to delete all the Duplicate after them. I still hope you can help me to solve my Problem.

```
SmartHome=# select * from sensordata order by time desc Limit 21;
 type | data |            time
------+------+----------------------------
    8 | 2459 | 2019-08-09 23:10:39.530087 << 
    8 | 2459 | 2019-08-09 23:10:39.356908
    8 | 2445 | 2019-08-09 23:05:39.933269 <<
    8 | 2445 | 2019-08-09 23:05:39.789173
   10 | 6105 | 2019-08-09 22:50:50.40792  <<
   10 | 6105 | 2019-08-09 22:50:50.096132
    8 | 2459 | 2019-08-09 22:50:41.429681 <<
    8 | 2459 | 2019-08-09 22:50:41.357483
    8 | 2474 | 2019-08-09 22:45:42.13396  <<
    8 | 2474 | 2019-08-09 22:45:41.813046
   10 | 6221 | 2019-08-09 22:40:51.107709 <<
   10 | 6221 | 2019-08-09 22:40:51.076903
   10 | 6105 | 2019-08-09 22:35:51.737255 <<
   10 | 6105 | 2019-08-09 22:35:51.544886
   10 | 6221 | 2019-08-09 22:30:52.493895 <<
   10 | 6221 | 2019-08-09 22:30:51.795203
    8 | 2459 | 2019-08-09 22:30:43.193447 <<
    8 | 2459 | 2019-08-09 22:30:43.045599
   10 | 6105 | 2019-08-09 22:25:52.571793 << Duplicate like them above
   10 | 6105 | 2019-08-09 22:25:52.442844 << Also a Duplicate with much more
   10 | 6105 | 2019-08-09 22:20:51.356846    time between the rows
(21 rows)

SmartHome=# \d sensordata
                   Table "public.sensordata"
 Column |            Type             |       Modifiers
--------+-----------------------------+------------------------
 type   | integer                     | not null
 data   | character varying(20)       | not null
 time   | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
Indexes:
    "smarthome_idx" UNIQUE, btree (type, "time")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "sensordata_type_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES sensortype(id)
```

If i run

```
with a as (Select *, row_number() over(partition by type,data order by time) from sensordata) select * from a where row_number=1 order by time desc;
```

the output is:

```
 10 | 17316 | 2019-08-09 09:43:46.938507 |          1
   10 | 18276 | 2019-08-09 09:38:47.129788 |          1
   10 | 18176 | 2019-08-09 09:33:47.889064 |          1
   10 | 17107 | 2019-08-08 10:36:11.383106 |          1
   10 | 17921 | 2019-08-08 09:56:15.889191 |          1
   10 | 17533 | 2019-08-03 09:30:11.047639 |          1
```

thats not what i mean :/ (ßorry dont know how to mark the stuff as code block in the comment therfore this way

Comment: Insert the records into another table with select distinct and the miliseconds trimmed off.  The insert the results back into sensor data.

Comment: You'll miss duplicates that go over a second boundary though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible ways to do this. The fastest is often a correlated subquery but I can never remember the syntax so I normally go for window functions, specifically row_number().

If you run

```
Select *, row_number() over(partition by type,data order by date) from sensor data
```

That should give a version of your table where all the rows you want to keep have a number 1 and the duplicates are numbered 2,3,4... Use that same field in a delete query and you'll be sorted.

EDIT: I understand now you only want to remove duplicates that occur sequentially within the same type. This can also be achieved using row_number and join.This query should give you only the data you want.

```
WITH s as (SELECT *,row_number() over(partition by type order by date) as rnum from sensordata)
SELECT a.* 
FROM s a 
JOIN s b 
ON a.rnum=b.rnum+1 AND a.type=b.type
WHERE NOT a.data=b.data
```

This might need a slight tweak to avoid missing the very first entry if that's important.

Comment: I merge my Comment into the question, beacuse i dont know how to commment a codeblock :/

Comment: with this querry i would i got not all duplicates, eg this one is still there

        `10 | 6105  | 2019-08-10 00:35:47.137982 | 32616
`
        ` 8 | 2459  | 2019-08-10 00:35:46.906772 | 32615
`
        `10 | 6105  | 2019-08-10 00:29:47.087688 | 32614
`

Comment: I literally just edited my answer in response to feedback on the other answer. Try the new version.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the duplicates using `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(time) over (partition by type, data order by time) as prev_time
      from sensordata t
     ) t
where prev_time > time - interval '10 minute';
```

This assumes an interval of 10 minutes for a duplicate.  You don't specify in the question.

Then, you can delete these using a `join`.  It would be better if you had a serial primary key, so you knew that data was unique.  But it seems reasonable to assume that `type`/`data`/`time` will be unique.

So:

```
delete t
    from (select t.*,
                 lag(time) over (partition by type, data order by time) as prev_time
          from sensordata t
         ) tt
    where tt.prev_time > t.time - interval '10 minute' and
          tt.type = t.type and
          tt.data = t.data and
          tt.time = t.time;
```

Note that if you do have exact duplicates in the table, then you might end up duplicating all the rows for a given combination, including the original one.

Comment: Good answer as I've learnt a new function, never knew about lag(). However we both made the mistake of assuming the OP wanted to partition by type. It seems that actually the requirement is to remove duplicate consecutive records with any amount of elapsed time but no partitioning. I've updated my answer to achieve this.

Comment: @SimonN . . . The question explicitly states:  "With duplicate I mean a tuples what is identically in the data to the last one from the same type."

Comment: So it does, not sure how I managed to misread that! Now my answer needs editing again.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select or delete records based on the existence of other records, `EXISTS()` is your friend.

First:

- define exactly what you consider a set of duplicates
- decide which one you want to keep, and which ones to delete

Assuming that you want to delete the most recent records, but **only if the data did not change** between the one to keep and the one to delete.

select the ones to delete:

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM sensordata d
WHERE EXISTS(                   -- if there exists a record with...
        SELECT * FROM sensordata x
        WHERE x.ztype = d.ztype -- the same type
        AND x.zdata = d.zdata   -- the same data
        AND x.ztime <d.ztime    -- but:older
        AND NOT EXISTS(                 -- and NO record exists with...
        SELECT * FROM sensordata nx
                WHERE nx.ztype = d.ztype -- the same type
                AND nx.zdata <> d.zdata -- but DIFFERENT data
                AND nx.ztime <d.ztime   -- between the one to delete
                AND nx.ztime >x.ztime   -- and the oldest one
                )
        );
```

---

If that looks OK, you can use exactly the same condition in a DELETE statement.

---

```
DELETE FROM sensordata d
WHERE EXISTS(                   -- if there exists a record with...
        SELECT * FROM sensordata x
        WHERE x.ztype = d.ztype -- the same type
        AND x.zdata = d.zdata   -- the same data
        AND x.ztime <d.ztime    -- but:older
        AND NOT EXISTS(                 -- and NO record exists with...
        SELECT * FROM sensordata nx
                WHERE nx.ztype = d.ztype -- the same type
                AND nx.zdata <> d.zdata -- but DIFFERENT data
                AND nx.ztime <d.ztime   -- between the one to delete
                AND nx.ztime >x.ztime   -- and the oldest one
                )
        );
```